# How have django async views changed in 3.2?

Tags: django, django-views

I've been learning how to use django for the past few weeks, and was looking into async view tutorials to try to see how they worked. I was watching one by Pyplane and noticed that the code no longer ran asynchronously. I looked into the documentation a bit more and it seemed like what he showed should have worked. I also tried hard coding it with asyncio and it gave me a SynchronousOnlyOperation error. Does anyone know a fix? Thanks in advance!

###### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async, async_to_sync
import asyncio
import time

from movies.models import Movie
from stories.models import Story

# Utils
def get_movies():
    print("Prepare to get the movies")
    time.sleep(2)
    qs = Movie.objects.all()
    print(qs)
    print("All movies retrieved")

def get_stories():
    print("Prepare to get the stories")
    time.sleep(5)
    qs = Story.objects.all()
    print(qs)
    print("All stories retrieved")

@sync_to_async
def get_movies_async():
    print("Prepare to get the movies")
    time.sleep(2)
    qs = Movie.objects.all()
    print(qs)
    print("All movies retrieved")

@sync_to_async
def get_stories_async():
    print("Prepare to get the stories")
    time.sleep(5)
    qs = Story.objects.all()
    print(qs)
    print("All stories retrieved")

# Views
def home_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello, World!</h1>')

def main_view(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    get_movies()
    get_stories()
    
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Sync Execution time: {total_time} second(s)")
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Sync</h1>')

async def main_view_async(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(get_movies_async())
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(get_stories_async())
    await asyncio.wait([task1, task2])
    # request_data = await asyncio.gather(
    #     get_movies_async(), 
    #     get_stories_async()
    # )
    
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Async Execution time: {total_time} second(s)")
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Async</h1>')
```

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YneIutRhmgo

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your Django version to 3.1. It will work.

```
pip install Django==3.1
```